# React Router: TypeError Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'originalPositionFor')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

Hi I am a beginner getting started with React Router, and generated the basic sources with create-react-app.

When I tried to setup the router according to the tutorial I get a TypeError.
I attempted to reduce any excess code that may cause the problem until I ended up with just this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import { Router } from 'react-router';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Yet I am still getting the same error

```
    ERROR in ./node_modules/history/index.js
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
    TypeError: /Users/Nanashi/reactjs/learning-my-blog/node_modules/history/index.js: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'originalPositionFor')
        at SourceMapTree.originalPositionFor (/Users/Nanashi/reactjs/learning-my-blog/node_modules/@ampproject/remapping/dist/remapping.umd.js:159:27)
        at trace (/Users/Nanashi/reactjs/learning-my-blog/node_modules/@ampproject/remapping/dist/remapping.umd.js:102:37)
        at EncodedSourceMapImpl.map (/Users/Nanashi/reactjs/learning-my-blog/node_modules/@jridgewell/trace-mapping/dist/trace-mapping.umd.js:347:36)
        at TraceMap.map (/Users/Nanashi/reactjs/learning-my-blog/node_modules/@jridgewell/trace-mapping/dist/trace-mapping.umd.js:430:31)
        at SourceMapTree.traceMappings (/Users/Nanashi/reactjs/learning-my-blog/node_modules/@ampproject/remapping/dist/remapping.umd.js:85:34)
        at remapping (/Users/Nanashi/reactjs/learning-my-blog/node_modules/@ampproject/remapping/dist/remapping.umd.js:258:36)
        at mergeSourceMap (/Users/Nanashi/reactjs/learning-my-blog/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/file/merge-map.js:19:30)
        at generateCode (/Users/Nanashi/reactjs/learning-my-blog/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/file/generate.js:72:39)
        at run (/Users/Nanashi/reactjs/learning-my-blog/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:55:33)
        at run.next (<anonymous>)
     @ ./node_modules/react-router/index.js 12:0-65 96:25-44 182:21-31 195:19-28 516:62-71 620:51-60 893:31-40 917:39-48 962:74-83
     @ ./src/index.js 8:0-38 10:38-44

    webpack 5.68.0 compiled with 1 error in 2579 ms
```

Using version 6.2.1

```
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router": "^6.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0"
```

I am completely baffled, any help is appreciated.

### Edit

I think I found the problem. It appears that `babel/core@7.17.0` had a breaking change that caused this issue (https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ui/issues/1242). I used the solution from this comment https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ui/issues/1242#issuecomment-1028471472, set my dependency to babel/core@17.16.12 and the error went away

Comment: Seems to be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70965112/cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-originalpositionfor Perhaps there's an intermittent issue with npm right now as both posts are the same error and only minutes apart.

Comment: you are right, sorry I didn't see that post before I posted mine

Answer (score 7):

There was an issue inside of `@jridgewell/trace-mapping` package.

The issue is already fixed and new version `v0.2.3` was published.

If you are using npm7+ all you need to do is run `npm update` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like somebody made a mistake in the last version of react router dom. It's a bug that you can fix typing this in the console:

`npm i -D @babel/core@7.16.12`

Then follow any example in the documentation and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix! There's already a patch available. Run `npm update`. Kudos to https://stackoverflow.com/a/70966285/214702

Answer (score 0):

Go to **./node_modules/history/index.js**

You will see something like this:

```
import _extends from'@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/extends';var r,B=r||(r={});B.Pop="POP";B.Push="PUSH";B.Replace="REPLACE";var C="production"!==process.env.NODE_ENV?function(b){return Object.freeze(b)}:function(b){return b};function D(b,h){if(!b){"undefined"!==typeof console&&console.warn(h);try{throw Error(h);}catch(e){}}}function E(b){b.preventDefault();b.returnValue=""}
function F(){var b=[];return{get length(){return b.length},push:function(h){b.push(h);return function(){b=b.filter(function(e){return e!==h})}},call:function(h){b.forEach(function(e){return e&&e(h)})}}}function H(){return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2,8)}function I(b){var h=b.pathname;h=void 0===h?"/":h;var e=b.search;e=void 0===e?"":e;b=b.hash;b=void 0===b?"":b;e&&"?"!==e&&(h+="?"===e.charAt(0)?e:"?"+e);b&&"#"!==b&&(h+="#"===b.charAt(0)?b:"#"+b);return h}
function J(b){var h={};if(b){var e=b.indexOf("#");0<=e&&(h.hash=b.substr(e),b=b.substr(0,e));e=b.indexOf("?");0<=e&&(h.search=b.substr(e),b=b.substr(0,e));b&&(h.pathname=b)}return h}
function createBrowserHistory(b){function h(){var c=p.location,a=m.state||{};return[a.idx,C({pathname:c.pathname,search:c.search,hash:c.hash,state:a.usr||null,key:a.key||"default"})]}function e(c){return"string"===typeof c?c:I(c)}function x(c,a){void 0===a&&(a=null);return C(_extends({pathname:q.pathname,hash:"",search:""},"string"===typeof c?J(c):c,{state:a,key:H()}))}function z(c){t=c;c=h();v=c[0];q=c[1];d.call({action:t,location:q})}function A(c,a){function f(){A(c,a)}var l=r.Push,k=x(c,
a);if(!g.length||(g.call({action:l,location:k,retry:f}),!1)){var n=[{usr:k.state,key:k.key,idx:v+1},e(k)];k=n[0];n=n[1];try{m.pushState(k,"",n)}catch(G){p.location.assign(n)}z(l)}}function y(c,a){function f(){y(c,a)}var l=r.Replace,k=x(c,a);g.length&&(g.call({action:l,location:k,retry:f}),1)||(k=[{usr:k.state,key:k.key,idx:v},e(k)],m.replaceState(k[0],"",k[1]),z(l))}function w(c){m.go(c)}void 0===b&&(b={});b=b.window;var p=void 0===b?document.defaultView:b,m=p.history,u=null;p.addEventListener("popstate",
function(){if(u)g.call(u),u=null;else{var c=r.Pop,a=h(),f=a[0];a=a[1];if(g.length)if(null!=f){var l=v-f;l&&(u={action:c,location:a,retry:function(){w(-1*l)}},w(l))}else"production"!==process.env.NODE_ENV?D(!1,"You are trying to block a POP navigation to a location that was not created by the history library. The block will fail silently in production, but in general you should do all navigation with the history library (instead of using window.history.pushState directly) to avoid this situation."):
void 0;else z(c)}});var t=r.Pop;b=h();var v=b[0],q=b[1],d=F(),g=F();null==v&&(v=0,m.replaceState(_extends({},m.state,{idx:v}),""));return{get action(){return t},get location(){return q},createHref:e,push:A,replace:y,go:w,back:function(){w(-1)},forward:function(){w(1)},listen:function(c){return d.push(c)},block:function(c){var a=g.push(c);1===g.length&&p.addEventListener("beforeunload",E);return function(){a();g.length||p.removeEventListener("beforeunload",E)}}}};
function createHashHistory(b){function h(){var a=J(m.location.hash.substr(1)),f=a.pathname,l=a.search;a=a.hash;var k=u.state||{};return[k.idx,C({pathname:void 0===f?"/":f,search:void 0===l?"":l,hash:void 0===a?"":a,state:k.usr||null,key:k.key||"default"})]}function e(){if(t)c.call(t),t=null;else{var a=r.Pop,f=h(),l=f[0];f=f[1];if(c.length)if(null!=l){var k=q-l;k&&(t={action:a,location:f,retry:function(){p(-1*k)}},p(k))}else"production"!==process.env.NODE_ENV?D(!1,"You are trying to block a POP navigation to a location that was not created by the history library. The block will fail silently in production, but in general you should do all navigation with the history library (instead of using window.history.pushState directly) to avoid this situation."):
void 0;else A(a)}}function x(a){var f=document.querySelector("base"),l="";f&&f.getAttribute("href")&&(f=m.location.href,l=f.indexOf("#"),l=-1===l?f:f.slice(0,l));return l+"#"+("string"===typeof a?a:I(a))}function z(a,f){void 0===f&&(f=null);return C(_extends({pathname:d.pathname,hash:"",search:""},"string"===typeof a?J(a):a,{state:f,key:H()}))}function A(a){v=a;a=h();q=a[0];d=a[1];g.call({action:v,location:d})}function y(a,f){function l(){y(a,f)}var k=r.Push,n=z(a,f);"production"!==process.env.NODE_ENV?
D("/"===n.pathname.charAt(0),"Relative pathnames are not supported in hash history.push("+JSON.stringify(a)+")"):void 0;if(!c.length||(c.call({action:k,location:n,retry:l}),!1)){var G=[{usr:n.state,key:n.key,idx:q+1},x(n)];n=G[0];G=G[1];try{u.pushState(n,"",G)}catch(K){m.location.assign(G)}A(k)}}function w(a,f){function l(){w(a,f)}var k=r.Replace,n=z(a,f);"production"!==process.env.NODE_ENV?D("/"===n.pathname.charAt(0),"Relative pathnames are not supported in hash history.replace("+JSON.stringify(a)+
")"):void 0;c.length&&(c.call({action:k,location:n,retry:l}),1)||(n=[{usr:n.state,key:n.key,idx:q},x(n)],u.replaceState(n[0],"",n[1]),A(k))}function p(a){u.go(a)}void 0===b&&(b={});b=b.window;var m=void 0===b?document.defaultView:b,u=m.history,t=null;m.addEventListener("popstate",e);m.addEventListener("hashchange",function(){var a=h()[1];I(a)!==I(d)&&e()});var v=r.Pop;b=h();var q=b[0],d=b[1],g=F(),c=F();null==q&&(q=0,u.replaceState(_extends({},u.state,{idx:q}),""));return{get action(){return v},get location(){return d},
createHref:x,push:y,replace:w,go:p,back:function(){p(-1)},forward:function(){p(1)},listen:function(a){return g.push(a)},block:function(a){var f=c.push(a);1===c.length&&m.addEventListener("beforeunload",E);return function(){f();c.length||m.removeEventListener("beforeunload",E)}}}};
function createMemoryHistory(b){function h(d,g){void 0===g&&(g=null);return C(_extends({pathname:t.pathname,search:"",hash:""},"string"===typeof d?J(d):d,{state:g,key:H()}))}function e(d,g,c){return!q.length||(q.call({action:d,location:g,retry:c}),!1)}function x(d,g){u=d;t=g;v.call({action:u,location:t})}function z(d,g){var c=r.Push,a=h(d,g);"production"!==process.env.NODE_ENV?D("/"===t.pathname.charAt(0),"Relative pathnames are not supported in memory history.push("+JSON.stringify(d)+")"):
void 0;e(c,a,function(){z(d,g)})&&(m+=1,p.splice(m,p.length,a),x(c,a))}function A(d,g){var c=r.Replace,a=h(d,g);"production"!==process.env.NODE_ENV?D("/"===t.pathname.charAt(0),"Relative pathnames are not supported in memory history.replace("+JSON.stringify(d)+")"):void 0;e(c,a,function(){A(d,g)})&&(p[m]=a,x(c,a))}function y(d){var g=Math.min(Math.max(m+d,0),p.length-1),c=r.Pop,a=p[g];e(c,a,function(){y(d)})&&(m=g,x(c,a))}void 0===b&&(b={});var w=b;b=w.initialEntries;w=w.initialIndex;var p=(void 0===
b?["/"]:b).map(function(d){var g=C(_extends({pathname:"/",search:"",hash:"",state:null,key:H()},"string"===typeof d?J(d):d));"production"!==process.env.NODE_ENV?D("/"===g.pathname.charAt(0),"Relative pathnames are not supported in createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries }) (invalid entry: "+JSON.stringify(d)+")"):void 0;return g}),m=Math.min(Math.max(null==w?p.length-1:w,0),p.length-1),u=r.Pop,t=p[m],v=F(),q=F();return{get index(){return m},get action(){return u},get location(){return t},createHref:function(d){return"string"===
typeof d?d:I(d)},push:z,replace:A,go:y,back:function(){y(-1)},forward:function(){y(1)},listen:function(d){return v.push(d)},block:function(d){return q.push(d)}}};export{r as Action,createBrowserHistory,createHashHistory,createMemoryHistory,I as createPath,J as parsePath}
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

Just uncomment out the last line

**sourceMappingURL=index.js.map**

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this problem with 2 comments

```
npm uninstall react-router-dom

npm i react-router-dom@5.2.0
```

Answer (score -1):

On the bash :

1. npm uninstall react-router-dom
2. npm i react-router-dom@6.0.2

My file package.json :

```
"react-router-dom": "^6.0.2"
```

My file app.js :

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import Home from "./pages/Home";


function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}  />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

it works for me !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).