# Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have read through a ton of posts on this and cannot find a solution. I built the app with Create-React-App so I didn't have to think about Babel/WebPack. I recently upgraded my dependencies and ran into this issue. The error is fairly lengthy, but here is the first part of bundle.js error...

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: .../src/StudentDashboard/ClientApp/node_modules/history/index.js: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'originalPositionFor')
```

The app is React on the fron end and .Net Core on the back end. I start the SPA from startup.cs with...

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
}
```

I have tried:

- running babel-upgrade with npx
- Adding babel.config.json with

```
"presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
```

- Adding dev dependencies of

```
"@babel/core": "^7.17.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
```

None of the above fixed the error. I even closed and restarted VS Code just in case. Any thoughts on how to fix would be appreciated.

Comment: are you using `react-router@5.x.x` with `history@5.x.x`? Because they are not compatible and you should stay on `history@4.x.x`

Comment: Here are the React entries from my package.json...
"react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.26.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
    "reactstrap": "^9.0.1",

I do not have history@. Should I?

Comment: I combed through my lock file and found that react-router (6.2.1) has a dependency of History: ^5.2.0

Comment: Looks like you could have your solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70965180/react-router-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-originalpo/70966285

Comment: I went through the link you shared and it did not fix my issue. Even though the post says a fix was made, I downgraded to core 7.16.12 and router-dom 5.2.0. Did not help. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue I was facing. While the error displayed pointed me towards Babel, which is what I thought, the real issue was related to changes to React routing.

I had to wrap all my `<route>` elements in a `<Routes>` tag. I then had to change the component attribute to element and place the component in html-like syntax...from `{Home}` to `{<Home/>}`.

One other change was that my import was pulling from react-router. I changed it to react-router-dom.

This was all in my App.js.

Here are a couple of links that might be helpful to others who, like me, did not realize there was a change.

- https://dev.to/gabrlcj/react-router-v6-some-of-the-new-changes-181m
- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/react-router-v6-what-changed-and-upgrading-guide/

Answer (score 1):

This error comes when you install the latest version of npm like this
npm install react-router-dom@6
after running npm start it will fail to compile because of @babel/core is incompatible with the npm version
so you have to revert back to babel previous versions
run this:

npm i -D @babel/core@7.16.12

the stop your development server and restart again

Answer (score 1):

my resolution was to delete node_modules, install again the yarn

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by `@jridgewell/trace-mapping` - a dependency of @babel/core, You can update it to fix the problem.
Reference link：
[[Bug]: Breaks react-router-dom #14229](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/14229)